# Pareto Optimal for more than four variables

Tags: r, optimization, pareto-optimality

I have a data frame with multiple outcomes, each with five variables, that I would like to optimize in R. I used `rPref` but this has a maximum of 4 variables to optimize. Does anyone know how to do this with more than four?

Comment: So multiobjective optimization with more than 4 objectives? Are you sure you need this (much complexity)? You may have to approximate the answer.

Comment: We may try to reduce the outcome variables.  Do you not think that more than 4 is feasible?

Comment: This depends a lot, of course, on your data, how much of it there is and how complex it is, so this could very well be feasible, it is hard to tell. But optimizing 4 objectives seems a little hard, also for interpretation. As an approximation you could try linear scalarization, just to test.

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of the [rPref](https://p-roocks.de/rpref) package. The information that rPref can calculate Pareto optima only for four variables is simply wrong. There is no limit for the number of optimization goals.

Consider the following small example: Let's create a data set `(a_1, ..., a_5)` with `a_i in {1, 2}` and `(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)` excluded:

```
library(listcompr)
df <- gen.data.frame(c(a_1, ..., a_5), a_ = 1:2, sum(a_1, ..., a_5) > 5)
```

The data set `df` has the following 31 entries:

```
> df
   a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4 a_5
1    2   1   1   1   1
2    1   2   1   1   1
3    2   2   1   1   1
[...]
30   1   2   2   2   2
31   2   2   2   2   2
```

Now let's minimize all 5 variables simultaneously with rPref:

```
> library(rPref)
> psel(df, low(a_1) * low(a_2) * low(a_3) * low(a_4) * low(a_5))
   a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4 a_5
1    2   1   1   1   1
2    1   2   1   1   1
4    1   1   2   1   1
8    1   1   1   2   1
16   1   1   1   1   2
```

The Pareto optima are exactly all tuples with exactly one "2", because `(2, 1, 1, 1, 1)` is Pareto-dominant to, e.g., `(2, 2, 1, 1, 1)`.